# mongoose query result can not export with data object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have a mongoose query
and I want update "entry_count" property of Entry object with result of count query
but I can't update exported data.

I can get data but can't export

this is my query code:

```
getTopicList: function(limit) {

    var deferred = promise.pending();
    // create mongoose model from schemas
    var Topic = mongoose.model('Topic');
    var Entry = mongoose.model('Entry');

    var queryDate = main.getCurrentDateString();
    // get entry count created in today
    Entry
    .count({createdAtStr : queryDate})
    .exec(function(err, entryCount) {
        // get last valid topics [ limit -> arg0 ]
        Topic
        .find({ status : 1 })
        .limit(limit)
        .sort('-updatedAt')
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            _.each(data, function(single) {
                Entry.
                count({topic : single._id})
                .exec(function(err, entryCnt) {
                    util.log(entryCnt);
                    single.entry_count = entryCnt;
                });
            });
            deferred.fulfill({"status":true,"data":data});
        });
    });


    return deferred.promise;

}
```

i can press log on console screen with util , but can't export updated data.
why can't do this?
please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fulfilling your promise too soon.  You shouldn't be calling `deferred.fulfill` until all the `exec` calls within the `_.each` have completed.

So something like:

```
Entry
.count({createdAtStr : queryDate})
.exec(function(err, entryCount) {
    // get last valid topics [ limit -> arg0 ]
    Topic
    .find({ status : 1 })
    .limit(limit)
    .sort('-updatedAt')
    .exec(function(err, data) {
        var numleft = data.length; // Count of outstanding count queries
        _.each(data, function(single) {
            Entry.
            count({topic : single._id})
            .exec(function(err, entryCnt) {
                util.log(entryCnt);
                single.entry_count = entryCnt;
                if (--numleft === 0) {
                    // None left, so fullfill the promise.
                    deferred.fulfill({"status":true,"data":data});
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: too thanks :) this worked and I understand source of problem :)